# ASP.NET Webforms project is reading from a web.config in a completely different solution on my PC when debugging

Tags: c#, vb.net, webforms, web-config

My web app is reading from a web.config from a completely different project with the same name in another solution. How can I check/change what web..config my project is referencing. I want to ensure it is the web.config in the current project.

Comment: You can check the project file to determine the path of the web.config. Easy way to fix might be to remove the current web.config in VS and then add the correct one back again.

Comment: It a connection string that you're trying to change, but the connection string originates from a class library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's got the same name (Copy of a project?), maybe your debugging settings are the same, e.g. do they use the same IIS Express port number?

Once you start a project IIS Express will remember where the code is. If you stop that project, open another and run it using the same port number it will get confused and view the code from the first project.

Comment: That is exactly what is happening. What should I do to prevent?

Comment: Assuming the code base is different, right click on your web project, choose properties > then the Web tab and just change the port number to something slightly different or "Override application root URL" if that doesn't work. The port is random to begin with so as long as it's unique and similar to what it currently is it should be fine.